# How do lambdas inside linq functions type parameters work?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have used Linq for a while, and lambdas in C#, but I couldn't find out how lambdas are aware of the parameters type in a collection, because, let's say for method .Any(), if I do something like in this, example from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
        class Pet
            {
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public int Age { get; set; }
                public bool Vaccinated { get; set; }
            }

        public static void AnyEx3()
        {
            // Create an array of Pets.
            Pet[] pets =
                { new Pet { Name="Barley", Age=8, Vaccinated=true },
                  new Pet { Name="Boots", Age=4, Vaccinated=false },
                  new Pet { Name="Whiskers", Age=1, Vaccinated=false } };

            // Determine whether any pets over age 1 are also unvaccinated.
            bool unvaccinated =
                pets.Any(p => p.Age > 1 && p.Vaccinated == false);

            Console.WriteLine(
                "There {0} unvaccinated animals over age one.",
                unvaccinated ? "are" : "are not any");
        }
```

the function .Any() knows that it has a parameter of type Pet inside the lambda expression. But if I am doing something like this:

```
(List<Pet> pets) => { return pets[0].Age; };
```

The type used in lambda must to be specified. I assume that the type is taken from inside the collection. Can somebody provide information about how are data types from the collections passed to extensions methods from Linq?

Comment: It's the magic of generics...

Comment: I think the keywords you should google for are "type inference". In many cases (such as your first example) the compiler can determine by itself which type you're talking about. If that's not possible, you have to specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the world of generics, you specify a type for the generic method either **implicitly or explicitly** (eg `TSource`) and all the other usages of `TSource` are of that type.

### For `Any`:

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) 
{

   foreach (TSource element in source) 
   {
       if (predicate(element)) 
       {
           return true;
       } 
       return false;
   }
}
```

Since `TSource` is of type `Pet`, the compiler infers that `Func<Pet, bool>` should be used, and so the lambda has an input of type Pet. And this is the source of Intellisense .

So, you either specify the type(s) **Explicitly**:

```
pets.Any<Pet>(p => p.Age > 10);
```

Or **Implicitly** (Infered by the compiler thought type of `pets` variable):

```
pets.Any(p => p.Age > 10);
```

Comment: Thank you, this example is very relevant to my question!

Comment: "In world of generics, you specify a generic type for the method" - except of course in this case and in quite a lot of cases we don't actually explicitly specify the generic type and instead allow the compiler to infer it.

Comment: Directly or indirectly, you have to specify the type. Whether explicitly or by a mean that the compiler can infer it.

Comment: @user3185569: Yup. I figured you knew what you meant but the answer was a little unclear and potentially confusing. Much better now! :)

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that the compiler does this for you.

It does this by two different methods. The first is something called type inference and this is used to work out what the generic types of your method are. To quote the spec:

> When a generic method is called without specifying type arguments, a
>   type inference process attempts to infer type arguments for the call.
>   The presence of type inference allows a more convenient syntax to be
>   used for calling a generic method, and allows the programmer to avoid
>   specifying redundant type information. *- Section N.5.2 of C# 5 spec*

The spec does of course go into precise detail of exactly how this process works.

To look at your case more closely when doing `pets.Any(...)` the compiler will look for valid methods and find the following matching extension method on Enumerable:

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate
)
```

In this case the first parameter is pets. Since `pets` implements `IEnumerable<Pets>` it can infer that `TSource` is `Pets`. It therefore knows that the type of the second parameter, `predicate`, is `Func<Pets, bool>`.

The second part is that the compiler recognises the lambda syntax as an anonymous function and anonymous functions can be implicitly converted to either a compatible delegate type or expression tree type. What that means is that you can use anonymous functions where the compiler is expecting a `Func`, `Action`, `Expression` or other delegate. So in this case it recognises that the lambda is a `Func<Pets, bool>` and will compile appropriately.